# Java or .net platform is good for creating interactive web page

Tags: openlayers-2, software-recommendations, java

I have just now completed my degree in Spatial Information Technology, and learned how to use the ARCGIS platform and QGIS. Now I wanted to create a server/client webpage using mapserver for a project work. In the future, I am planing to go more into the GIS developer side.

Can you advise on whether you think java or .net platform will be better for creating interactive web pages?

I would like to use open source tools like mapserver rather than ArcGIS Server due to cost.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation: If you do a general job search for GIS Developer, I think you will also notice that most are on the Java side. Especially the ones dealing a lot with open source (Geoserver, MapServer, OGC, etc.) Yes there are many ESRI development jobs in .NET, but other than that most are developing GIS solutions are in Java, python, PHP etc.

So if you want to be a GIS Developer and you want to be more marketable, go toward Java.

I'm a GIS Developer that has chosen .NET and personally regret not focusing more on Java.